# Angular 2 routing to page with pipe set

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-directives

I have a page that has a list of brands, then another page that has all of the products of each brand brought in from a service. The product page can be filtered by brand with a pipe. What I want to do is simple.

From the page with the list of brands i want to be able to go to the filtered product page by clicking on a brand link. This is the general product page, but with the filter already set on the brand. I want to be able to change the filter while I am there also.

For example, i have a list of shoe brands on a page: 
Adidas, Nike, Puma, Reebok
When I click on Adidas, it takes me to the dynamic product page with the content filtered by Adidas shoes. But if I want to look at Nike shoes, I can change the filter at the top of the product page I am on and have it filter by Nike shoes.

I have looked through the Angular.io documentation and the Meteor Tutorial with no success thus far. I have tried passing parameters in the link (`routerlink="['/product-page, product.brand']"`) and setting up the activatedRoute, but I'm not sure it applies here.
Any ideas?

Link on brands page

```
<a [routerLink]="['/product-page']">
  <div class="packs adidas">
    <!--<p>ADIDAS</p>-->
  </div>
</a>
```

filter markup

```
 <div class="filter">
  <label for="filter">FILTER</label>
  <div class="select-arrows-wrapper">
    <select name="filter" id="brand-filter" [(ngModel)]="productName">
      <option [value]="null">All Brands</option>
      <option *ngFor="let product of products | async | duplicate:'productId'" [value]="product.productName">{{product.productName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div> <!--end filter-->
```

relevant routes

```
{path: 'customer-brands', component: CustomerBrandsComponent},
{path: 'product-page', component: ProductPageComponent},
```

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: Have you looked at the first tutorial that angular2 has on its website. It's called tutorial of Heroes and it does exactly what you want. Take a look at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Brand ID to your product-page route, then read the ID in your ProductPageComponent.

For example:

```
{path: 'product-page/:brand', component: ProductPageComponent}
```

Then, in your ProductPageComponent, inject ActivatedRoute into the constructor, and retrieve the ID, like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

public brand string;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.brand = route.snapshot.params['brand']);
}
```

You can now use the variable `brand` to filter your data.

You will also need to change your routerLink so it appends the brand to the end of the url - for example:

```
<a [routerLink] ="['/product-page/' + product.brand]">Test</a>
```

Comment: This worked exactly how i wanted it to. We are going to be using this in many places so I appreciate you breaking it down. Thanks!

Comment: how would i pass in a default value so that I can still access the products page? Or how would I configure the route? I still need to access "/products-page"

Comment: Just add two routes - 
`{path: 'product-page', component: ProductPageComponent},
{path: 'product-page/:brand', component: ProductPageComponent}`

And check to see if brand is populated or not in your constructor.

Comment: **Nevermind.** I just added a blank "/product-page" route. Thanks again for your help.  (we wrote this at the same time i guess haha"

Comment: hah, sounds like it!  Glad to help!  I'd be grateful if you could mark the above post as the answer, if you feel it suitably answers your original question :)